# Connecting to MySQL from a Django project in Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to connect to MySQL database from a Django project and I have this error:  "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?".

I have already installed mysqlclient with this command: 
`pip install mysqlclient`

In my Django project's settings.py file I have changed the database to this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_django',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019. Django version: 2.2.9. Python version: 3.8.1 & Xampp for the MySQL.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Good [walkthrough](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database) here.  You may need python-dev and libmysqlclient-dev.

Comment: the commands in the link for installing python-dev and libmysqlclient-dev is not working

Comment: I don't know if anyone is reading this a year later but I tried installing the mysql p connector via the pip command line and it didn't work, but I had more luck when I installed it through Visual Studio. Right click on Python 3 (assuming that's your version) in  Solution Explorer, select "Manage Python Packages" and it should be obvious from there.